# How to align the nth column that has multiple lines

Tags: bash, awk, ksh, aix

I am having 3 variables that I use printf to align their outputs 
I know the first env var is one line so the 2nd var as well
The problem with the 3rd var is that this variable has huge output hence I would like to list them aligned ( i hope below would clear my question )

** I don't have column command **

I am using

`printf "%-20s %-5s %-20s \n" "${OUT}" "${COUNT}" "${DATA}"`

```
OUT11                OUT2  OUT3
----------           ----- --------------
GATE1                14    CU4 CU2 CU9var CU3 CU1 CU11admin CU10opt not_sy 
CU_doonce cutttCU clocal_CU global_CU tivoli_CU 
GATE2                70    gdba_CU cdba_CU vudb_CU tti1_CU tti3_CU tt3_CU
3c2_CU tt3c3_CU tt3c4_CU tt3d1_CU tt3a1_CU tt3u1
3t3_CU tt3t4_CU tt4_CU utt4_CU tt4c1_CU tt4c2_CU
4d1_CU tt4a1_CU tt4u1_CU tt4t1_CU tt4t2_CU tt4t3
tt5_CU tt5c1_CU tt5c2_CU tt5c3_CU tt5c4_CU tt5d1
5t1_CU tt5t2_CU tt5t3_CU tt5t4_CU tt6_CU utt6_CU
6c3_CU tt6c4_CU tt6d1_CU tt6a1_CU tt6u1_CU tt6t1
6t4_CU tt7_CU utt7_CU tt7c1_CU tt7c2_CU tt7c3_CU
7a1_CU tt7u1_CU tt7t1_CU tt7t2_CU tt7t3_CU tt7t4
```

and I need them as:

```
OUT11                OUT2  OUT3
----------           ----- --------------
GATE1                14    CU4 CU2 CU9var CU3 CU1 CU11admin CU10opt not_sy 
                           CU_doonce cutttCU clocal_CU global_CU tivoli_CU 
GATE2                70    gdba_CU cdba_CU vudb_CU tti1_CU tti3_CU tt3_CU
                           3c2_CU tt3c3_CU tt3c4_CU tt3d1_CU tt3a1_CU tt3u1
                           3t3_CU tt3t4_CU tt4_CU utt4_CU tt4c1_CU tt4c2_CU
                           4d1_CU tt4a1_CU tt4u1_CU tt4t1_CU tt4t2_CU tt4t3
                           tt5_CU tt5c1_CU tt5c2_CU tt5c3_CU tt5c4_CU tt5d1
                           5t1_CU tt5t2_CU tt5t3_CU tt5t4_CU tt6_CU utt6_CU
                           6c3_CU tt6c4_CU tt6d1_CU tt6a1_CU tt6u1_CU tt6t1
                           6t4_CU tt7_CU utt7_CU tt7c1_CU tt7c2_CU tt7c3_CU
                           7a1_CU tt7u1_CU tt7t1_CU tt7t2_CU tt7t3_CU tt7t4
```

Comment: Having shell variables with names like OUT COUNT and DATA and trying to print them in that way implies you have gone off the rails and are trying to use a shell script to do something shells weren't designed to do, i.e. text processing. Post a new question if you'd like help doing whatever it is you're doing the right way rather than putting band-aids on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
your_command | awk '
/GATE/{
  val=index($0,$3)
  while(++i<val){
    space=space OFS
  }
}
!/^GATE/{
  $0=space $0
}
1'
```

One liner:

```
your_command | awk '/GATE/{val=index($0,$3);while(++i<val){space=space OFS}} !/^GATE/{$0=space $0} 1'
```

OR as per Ed sir's comment try following:

```
your_command | awk '
/GATE/{
  space=sprintf("%*s",index($0,$3),"")
}
!/^GATE/{
  $0=space $0
}
1'
```

Comment: not sure how to use your code within my printf line

Comment: @mshafey, You need NOT to use this in printf, just run code with your Input_file and see what happens.

Comment: @mshafey, pipe your loop with `echo $OUT $COUNT $DATA` to it

Comment: I passed above awk but the it gave the exact same result

Comment: @mshafey, Please pass your complete command like 'some echo commands | then above command` etc as an example and try then?

Comment: my script name is cld, it gave the bad output that i need to align -- i am using your code as >> #./cld | (YOUR awk) is that correct?

Comment: @mshafey, yes in case you a script do it like `your_script.sh | my awk code` and lemme know then?

Comment: `val=index($0,$3); while(++i<val){
    space=space OFS
  }` = `space=sprintf("%*s",index($0,$3),"")`.

Comment: @EdMorton, Thank you sir I added that solution now, thank you for letting me know sir, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
OUT="GATE1"
COUNT="14"
DATA="CU4 CU2 CU9var CU3 CU1 CU11admin CU10opt not_sy CU_doonce cutttCU clocal_CU global_CU tivoli_CU"
while [[ -n $DATA ]]
do
    printf "%-20s %-5s %-20s \n" "${OUT}" "${COUNT}" "${DATA:0:48}"
    OUT=" "
    COUNT=" "
    DATA="${DATA:48}"
done
```

Comment: "${DATA:0:48}": 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.

Comment: @mshafey is that an error occurring when running what i wrote above as a script? if so, what version of Bash?

Comment: bash version is bash-5.0-2

Comment: running the above script works for me in both `4.4` and `5.0`. You just save whole above block to file and execute it, or paste it directly into interactive bash, and have this error?

Comment: yes saved yours in a file and it gave above error note this is not linux

Comment: seems to be a bug in bash on aix then, idk what else could it be

Comment: sure it could be -- i used to see differences between bash on aix and linux

Comment: Pragmatic fix: Try `DATA="${DATA:48:1000}"`? Note that this does not split on spaces or newlines in the data, but that is more work. It will look wrong if there are newlines in the data.

Comment: @GemTaylor it's the `:0:48` parameter expansion that fails

Comment: Ok, perhaps use the regex stuff: `if [[ "$data =~ ^(.{48,48})(.*)$ ]] ; then` `printnow="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` `data="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"` `else` `printnow="$data"` `data=` `fi`

Comment: @GemTaylor we need to wrap it in a while(0) with a break

Comment: Be aware that the OP is running on an AIX system and probably an old version of KSH. The error in the first comment seems to point at that.

Comment: @kvantour unless they sourced the script into `ksh` by accident, they run `bash-5.0-2` like they mentioned above. but yeah error seems to point at that.

Comment: My regex suggestion was just as an alternative to the 1 phrase `${DATA:0:48}` you would still need the rest of the loop code. On the other hand this is 100% bash, and if you have now decided your script engine is not bash, this also will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You make use of the following line to print your lines:

```
$ printf "%-20s %-5s %-20s \n" "${OUT}" "${COUNT}" "${DATA}"
```

The problem you have is that `${DATA}` contains newline characters. We can infer this because you attempt to print a string longer than 20 characters in a 20-character-wide field (your format shows this). It are these newline characters that ensure that your DATA continues at the beginning of the next line. If you want to align them, you have to make a small substitution of your newlines in that variable.

Example:

```
$ p=$'foo\nbar'
$ printf "%-2s %1s\n" "a" "$p"
a  foo
bar
$ printf "%-2s %1s\n" "a" "${p//$'\n'/$'\n'   }"
a  foo
   bar
```

You know that the DATA column must start on character 28. So there are 27 characters in front of it (20+1+5+1). So all you need to do is:

```
$ printf "%-20s %-5s %-20s \n" "${OUT}" "${COUNT}" "${DATA//$'\n'/$'\n'$(printf "%27s" "")}"
```

This should work in bash or a modern ksh. If you do not have this, and variable substitution does recognize `${var//str/repl}`, then you can quicklly postprocess that single line with `awk`:

```
$ printf "%-20s %-5s %-20s \n" "${OUT}" "${COUNT}" "${DATA}" \
  | gawk -v RS= '{gsub(ORS,ORS sprintf("%27s",""))}1'
```

Comment: ./cld3[11]: ""${fs//$"\\n"/$"\\n"$(printf "%27s" "")}"": 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.

Comment: @mshafey seems you have double backslashes.

Comment: I used $ printf "%-20s %-5s %-20s \n" "${OUT}" "${COUNT}" "${DATA//$'\n'/$'\n'$(printf "%27s" "")}"

Comment: it gave error as >>> ./cld3[11]: "${fs//$\n/$\n$(printf "%27s" "")}": 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.

Comment: @mshafey which shell are you using and which system?

Comment: Does the example work for you that I presented above?

Comment: It seems you are not running BASH but an old version of KSH, is this possible?

Comment: ksh on aix not linux

Comment: however i am having some feature from bash installed here but not the fully bash we used to find within linux systems -- anyway i can confirm i am ksh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202054/discussion-between-mshafey-and-kvantour).